# Error 'S' is not a valid?

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to Create splash screen on Android Studio and i have this Little problem with the code

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_weight="match_parent"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="splash">

    <TextView android:text="splash screen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textsize="45dp"
        android:layout_aligmParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/preview"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(Error:Error: 'S' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore).

All the s is lowercase
I do not know what is the problem .

images to the problem

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYv2f.png

Comment: try typing `s` in place of all `s` looking character by hand

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try changing the filename `Splash.xml` to all lowercase: `splash.xml`. I have a vague memory that it might matter.

Comment: Thank you that work but i got Another problem .

Error:(1) String types not allowed (at 'layout_weight' with value 'match_parent').

Comment: @mlkalr3b Yeah, I searched a bit now and just found a duplicate question addressing the very same issue.

Comment: Alright can you help me with this
Error:(1) String types not allowed (at 'layout_weight' with value 'match_parent').

Comment: @mlkalr3b I'm not that familiar with Android (only a beginner myself), but I don't see the `layout_weight` attribute as available for RelativeLayout at all. Maybe you need to use a different layout too.

Comment: @mlkalr3b I would create a new question for that problem so that some more experienced Android devs can see it.

Comment: `layout_weight` is a float value specifying relative weight in a `LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks! It worked.